# How can I access a top-level model from within a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, module

In this application, there are two very similar models: `/app/models/material.rb` and `app/models/projects/material.rb`. The `projects` namespace is part a module which exists within this application.

Inside `/app/controllers/projects/materials_controller` I'm attempting to update a material based on the root namespace's material attributes. (It's a synchronization of sorts, updating the cost.)

Inside the scope of this controller, though, `Material` is actually `Projects::Material`. I need to get access to `Material` at this point.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following syntax:

```
::Material
```

Answer (score 5):

You can prepend `::` to access the top-level namespace from within a module. `::Material` should refer to your model.

Comment: Thank you for the help! @Slicedpan gets credit since he/she was just a little quicker.

Comment: Modified my question after you explained what I was trying to do. Thanks for that as well.